# How do I import angular/http

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular, ecmascript-5, node-modules

I'm building an app in Visual studio using gulp and node.

Node puts all dependencies into a node_modules folder, when I build, gulp copies those to a libs folder in wwwroot.

I've been using other angular imports like component with out issue, but when I try this

```
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
```

I get a 404 when the page loads.

It looks like its trying to load angular/http from `http://localhost:8273/angular2/http`

I'm using Angular2 beta8, and targeting es5 to get around other issues.

So, how do I get rid of the 404, where do I configure it to look under the libs/angular folder for the http js file?

I tried typing that straight into the import, but kept getting not found errors.

Comment: Did you try importing from 'lib/angular2/http'?

Comment: have you added `http.dev.js` file to index page? I don't know how to do it with node's NPM. But this reference is necessary !

Comment: If I try importing from lib/angular2/http I get a error `Can't find module ...`
I can't actually find http.dev.js in the angular folder. Not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: Just found the http.dev.js file in the bundles folder, looks like that was the ticket, thanks.

Comment: Oh great !nice enjoy `Angular2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the http.dev.js from the node_modules/angular2/bundles folder in your HTML entry file:

```
<script src=" node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```